# Getting "object doesn't support property or method 'show'" when creating a new mulitmedia object in Tridion R5

Tags: content-manager, 5.3

Backstory:

I am running IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode, but have also tried this on IE8 and IE7  native.

server is in Europe, I'm in the US. When attempting to create a new multimedia object in `Tridion R5`, I click on "schema" to access the drop down and get the following error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'show'

The error also occurs when right clicking on an object The really strange part is that in Europe, the system works properly (although not with my ID). Does Tridion (or can it) use other rights than what is set in Tridion itself? It appears to me that perhaps the call to open the dropdown is accessing a resource that I don't have access to. Is that a possibility, or does anyone else have any ideas?

I don't have access to the server itself, and our support has been sketchy at best, so I'd like to try to point them in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mention Tridion R5, any more details on that, are we talking R5.2 or R5.3?

Comment: Sorry, it's 5.3 Build 5.3.0.63 for CM Explorer, 5.3.0.994 for CMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my 2 cents

- Go to Tools > Internet Options > Security Tab > Local Intranet -> Custom Level
- Change the settings to match the below
- ActiveX controls and plug-ins > Allow Scriptlets = Enable
- Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains
- Miscellaneous > Allow scripting of Internet Explorer Browser control = Enable
- Miscellaneous > Use Pop-up Blocker = Disable
- Scripting > Allow Programmatic clipboard access = Enable
- Ensure Tridion Is enabled for Popups
- Go to Tools > Popup Blocker > Popup Blocker Settings
- On the settings screen add http://tridion.yourdomain.com as an Allowed Site
- Disable any thirdparty toolbar etc.
- Clear Cache and Close down IE completely.

Comment: WONDERFUL!    all settings were correct EXCEPT for "Access data sources across domains" and now it works  Thank you for your help

Comment: Great if it helped you please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add the site you are using for access the CMS to the Trusted Sites in IE and refresh the page

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-zones-adding-removing-websites#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Thank you.  I have already tried that, I should have mentioned in the original post that I went through all the settings in IE per Tridion's manual and ensured they were all set as Tridion requires.

Comment: Also select the option "Allow Scriptlets"                 Tools-> Internet Options-> Security-> Custom Level-> ActiveX controls and plug-ins.
On the Allow Scriptlets setting, select the Enable radio button.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I recommend to compare the browser settings (The one in Europe and yours) plus verify if maybe the browser settings are setup by company policy and is not allowing you to make changes